# What's this CS my kernel keeps rejecting?

Tags: kernel, amd-radeon

I'm pretty sure this is being caused by my graphics card (*ati r12xx* or something) and its crappy Linux driver. I am **not** asking how to fix this problem. I **am** simply asking what does this "*CS*" mean?

I'm trying to run a piece of software on my Linux machine, but I'm running into this error report:

```
radeon: The kernel rejected CS, see dmesg for more information.
```

This error happens during runtime. It doesn't crash the application, but does cause visual distortion of loaded images. Like I said, it is related to my graphics card. I just want to know what "CS" means, for educational reasons.

I can post the `dmesg` output here if necessary, but I really don't care about the error itself right now.

Comment: You would need the error for more details, but without context I would say it stands for Context Switch.

Comment: Why did you delete your question on Stack Overflow? They can migrate it for you.

Comment: @TomWijsman No reason really. Didn't know it made a difference. =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command Stream. Trying to send it something it does not understand? mabey because it is compressed and it doesnt know how to decompress or didnt decompress properly?